# $\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb Z_n$ is cyclic if and only if $\gcd(m,n)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-product

> Let $m,n$ be positive integers bigger than $1$. Show that $\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb Z_n$ is cyclic if and only if $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

I have no idea on how to start. Anyone hints are much helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hint 1: Suppose $d = \gcd(m,n) > 1$.  Then $k = \frac{mn}{d}$ is an integer (why?) and every element of $\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ has order dividing $k$ (why?).  Conclude that $\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ cannot be cyclic in this case.

Hint 2: Suppose $d = \gcd(m,n) = 1$.  Consider the element $(1,1) \in \mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ and compute its order.  Conlcude that $\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ is cyclic in this case.

Comment: Can you tell me why every element of Zm x Zn has order dividing k?

Comment: @Math_QED: It is an easy calculation $k (a,b) = (0,0)$ for $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n$, since $k = m \cdot \frac{n}{d} = n \cdot \frac{m}{d}$, with each of $\frac{n}{d}$ and $\frac{m}{d}$ being integers. Then it follows that $\text{ord}(a,b) \mid k$.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't look at it that way! Thanks a lot haha :)

Comment: @Math_QED: Happy to help.