# The product of finitely many cyclic groups is cyclic iff the order of the groups are co-primes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups, direct-product

[$\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb Z_n$ is cyclic if and only if $\gcd(m,n)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310304/mathbbz-m-times-mathbb-z-n-is-cyclic-if-and-only-if-gcdm-n-1).

I know the question is a duplicate, I understand the proof for the case of two groups, but for some reason, I can't prove the general case of n groups by induction, and I couldn't find a proof either.

The proof in the case of two groups only uses the fact that gcd(a,b) divides a and b, but when we get to 3 numbers say a, b and c, I needed the fact that gcd(a,b)*gcd(a,c)*gcd(b,c) divides the product of any two of a,b,c, but that is not correct.

So, how to do the induction proof (I'm not interested in proving it by constructing an isomorphism, just using the same argument in the case of two groups)?

I'm stuck at the point where I need the fact that gcd(a,b)*gcd(a,c)*gcd(b,c) divides the product of any two of a,b,c. Is there a way to do the proof the same way as in the 2 groups case?

In the 2 groups case, we rais the generator to the power ab/gcd(a,b) and we get the identity, so we conclude that $ab\leq ab/gcd(a,b)$, so gcd(a,b)=1, where ab is the order of direct product group.

Comment: If you know the chinese theorem, then this should be straightforward, no ?

Comment: The orders must be _pairwise_ coprime. Then, one can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: "Is it necessary? "Please forgive me, but I think looking at this question without Chinese Remainder Theorem is something like looking at divisibility questions of integers and asking if the fundamental theorem of arithmetic is really necessary to know. If that's not in your book, look into another book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the result for 2 groups, then for 3 groups, you need two things:

- If $a,b,c$ are pairwise relatively prime, then $ab$ and $c$ are relatively prime.
- If $G$ is not cyclic, then neither is $G\times H$.

Then, if $G_1, G_2, G_3$ are cyclic with pairwise relatively prime orders, so are $G_1\times G_2$ and $G_3$, and therefore $(G_1\times G_2)\times G_3$ is cyclic.  And if the orders are not pairwise relatively prime, then either $G_1\times G_2$ is not cyclic (and so the product $(G_1 \times G_2)\times G_3$ is also not cyclic), or else $G_1\times G_2$ is cyclic but not of order relatively prime to $G_3$, so the product is agaian not cyclic.

The same logic here would then give a full induction proof for $n$ cyclic groups.

If you need help establishing the required fact about relatively prime numbers, the easiest way is to simply use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic to say that any prime dividing $c$ doesn't divide $a$ or $b$, and therefore doesn't divide $ab$.

Comment: I thought about that argument, but I thought it doesn't work, here is my concern:

Comment: Is $(G_1 \times G_2)\times G_3$ the same as  $G_1 \times G_2\times G_3$ ?

Comment: the element of the first is ((g,h),k) , while the other is (g,h,k), so aren't they different? the definition of the operation looks different

Comment: They are isomorphic as groups. In fact, some would say that Cartesian product is inherently a binary operation, but it is associative, and so just like how you can take the sum of 3 numbers in different ways to get the same result, you can take the product of sets/groups in different ways to get the same result. This perspective only works for finite products, but it works well there.